# xrandr multiple outputs, difference between --right-of and --pos

Tags: xrandr

I'm trying to use xrandr to set up two displays with different resolutions. My goal is to have them alinged at the bottom:

```
+-------------+
|             |
|             +---------+
|  Output A   |Output B |
|             |         |
+-------------+---------+
```

I've tryed using `xrandr --output B --right-of A`. They'll be aligned on the top, but the dead space below B won't be reachable for the mouse.
I've also tryed the `--pos` option to define the positions on the virtual screen. Now they're aligned on the bottom but the dead space above B will be reachable for the mouse.

Is there either a possibility to specify the position with the `--right-of` command or a possibility to block part of the virtual screen for the mouse?
It is totally possible to achive this via gui (e.g. arandr) but I need it in a script.

Answer (score 1):

see: https://superuser.com/q/485120/1132898

If this option were implemented, it would make the setup a bit easier.
https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2014-November/044624.html